# Функция Scanner не считывает последний параметр color

Tags: java, функции, scanner

Цель моей программы заполнить данные полей  об объекте Andrei с коавиатуры. Функция Scanner принимает все значения кросе последнего color. Я не могу заполнить значение Color. Вместо этого сразу выскакивает на экран информация о полях.Ниже прикладываю код результата в консоли.

```
ua.com.foxminded.school.School
Enter name of the first student: 
Andrei Kulagin
Enter gender of the first student: 
Male
Enter age of the first student: 
24
Enter score of the first student: 
5
Enter color of the first student: 
A{name='Andrei Kulagin', gender='Male', age=24, score=5, color=''}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ниже прикладываю мой код:

```
package ua.com.foxminded.school;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        A Andrei = new A();
        A Dima = new A();
        A Alex = new A();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name of the first student: ");
        Andrei.name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter gender of the first student: ");
        Andrei.gender = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter age of the first student: ");
        Andrei.age = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter score of the first student: ");
        Andrei.score = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter color of the first student: ");
        Andrei.color = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Andrei);


    }

}
```

Код класса А:

```
package ua.com.foxminded.school;

public class A {
    String name;
    String gender;
    int age;
    int score;
    String color;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", score=" + score +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanner.nextInt()` ждёт число
`scanner.nextLine()` ждёт и считывает конец строки (`"\n"`)

получается после ввода числа и нажатия "enter" автоматически отработает  `nextLine()`
надо заменить `scanner.nextLine()` на `scanner.next()`